# can't upgrade, password problems

Tags: password-recovery

I installed ubuntu without a password, However, I am asked for a password for upgrading, and restarting ubuntu. Is there a way to get around this? I have tried the various ways to discover what the password is - including using my old password and other forum tips - no luck.

Comment: If you used the standard Desktop or Server installers, it's not possible to install Ubuntu without a password. So please edit your question to clearly explain how you did install Ubuntu without a password. Maybe you used a cloud image?  Some vagrant box?  Something else?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. The standard installation of Ubuntu requires setting a password even if you set it to login automatically when you power-on the computer.

Comment: *I installed Ubuntu without a password*: How? Resetting the password is the only workaround here I believe. This might help [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: Probably set to automatic login and forgotten. Now somehow changed the settings.

Answer (score 0):

**Same old method**

- Switch the computer on. Go to Grub menu. it appears automatically, if not then hold down the shift key until the boot menu appears.
- In the grub menu, select the “Advanced Options for Ubuntu” and press "Enter".
- Navigate to the option ......(recovery mode) and press "Enter". Wait for few seconds till presented with different options.
- Choose “Root    Drop into root shell prompt“ press enter key.
- Option to enter commands appear in the bottom.
- *To remount file system with write access*. Command:

  ```
  mount -rw -o remount /
  ```
- then to choose the “username” Command:

  ```
  ls /home
  ```
- Reset the password.

  ```
  passwd username
  ```
- When prompted twice. Type new password

  ```
  Enter new UNIX password:
  Retype new UNIX password:
  ```

  and type

  ```
  exit
  ```
- Back to the recovery mode menu select "resume resumenormal boot" and press "Enter".
- log in with the new password.